# UWP: Display full size of image

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, contentdialog

I'm facing an issue in my UWP app where I'm attempting to display an image within a ContentDialog. However, the image gets cropped within the dialog, and I want it to be displayed without any clipping. Below is my current XAML code for the Image control within the ContentDialog

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="eseua.Views.ImageEditorDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:helpers="using:eseua.Helpers"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Width="Auto"
    Margin="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    CornerRadius="{StaticResource OverlayCornerRadius}"
    PrimaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
    PrimaryButtonText="{helpers:ResourceString Name=ExportHistoryNoteDialog_PrimaryButtonText}"
    SecondaryButtonStyle="{StaticResource ThemeAwareContentDialogSecondaryButtonStyle}"
    SecondaryButtonText="{helpers:ResourceString Name=Edit_Note_Discard_Changes_Discard}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical">

        <Grid x:Name="img_grid">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage x:Name="imageSource"  />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

and this is what I get
[image]

and this what i want to be displayed in the dialog

[image]

I've tried adjusting the Stretch property to 'Uniform' and adding HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalAlignment="Stretch" to the Image control, but the issue persists. How can I modify the XAML to ensure that the image is displayed without any cropping or clipping

Comment: Have you checked my reply about this unexcepted behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response. Thanks a lot for your help! The second solution worked perfectly, but the first one ("<Image x:Name="img" Stretch="Fill" Width="300" Height="500">") didn't worked , anyway thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Image width and height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image?view=winrt-22621#image-width-and-height),

> If you don't set Width and/or Height, and leave the image as its
> natural size, the Stretch property for the image can control how the
> image source file will fill the space you specify as Width and Height.

For example, the image you shared is 1003x653, so your image control will automatically become that size. However, your `img_grid` is not this size, (it may 400x500), so you cannot see the complete picture.

According to the code you provided, the workaround is to set the size of Image `<Image x:Name="img" Stretch="Fill" Width="300" Height="500">`  , or add ImageOpened event and resize the image after it is opened.

```
<Grid x:Name="img_grid">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Image x:Name="img" Stretch="Fill" ImageOpened="img_ImageOpened">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage x:Name="imageSource"  />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

```
private void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = sender as Image;
    image.Height = img_grid.ActualHeight;
    image.Width = img_grid.ActualWidth;
}
```